# Не подключаеться angular в расщирении chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

Есть расширение Chrome.  В при простому запуске html страницы скрипт работает.
Как загружаю в хром, скрипт не подключается.
Исходник:
http://zalil.su/3867918
Манифест:

```
{
    "manifest_version" : 2,
    "name" : "...",
    "short_name" : "...",
    "version" : "1.0",
    "author" : "...",
    "description" : "...",

    "icons" : {
        "16" : "icons/16x16.png",
        "32" : "icons/32x32.png",
        "48" : "icons/48x48.png",
        "64" : "icons/64x64.png",
        "128" : "icons/128x128.png"
    },

     "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "*://*/*" ],
      "js": [ "weather.js" ]
    }
  ],

    "background" : {

    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "...",
        "default_icon": "icons/water.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

Код

```js
var app = angular.module('jsbin', []);

app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($http) {

  var vm = this;
   var temp1=[];
var URL2;
  var URL = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily';

  var request = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: URL,
    params: {
       q: 'Petrozavodsk',
      mode: 'json',
      units: 'metric',
      cnt: '7',
      appid: '3ac1f68b653ffbf72a5f782420062771'
    }
  };

 $http(request)
    .then(function(response) {
   vm.data = response.data;
   vm.URL2="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/"+vm.data.list[0].weather[0].icon+".png";
   vm.mmrts=vm.data.list[0].pressure* 0.7500;
       }).
    catch(function(response) {
      vm.data = response.data;
      vm.URL2="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/"+vm.data.list[0].weather[0].icon+".png";

    });


});
```

```html
   
-<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular JS</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="jsbin">
  <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl as vm">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="weather.js"></script>

  <cityStyle>{{vm.data.city.name}} </cityStyle><br>
    <countryStyle>Country:{{vm.data.city.country}}</countryStyle>
    <br>
  <img src={{vm.URL2}} alt={{vm.data.list[0].weather[0].description}} title={{vm.data.list[0].weather[0].description}} >

<TempStyle>
   {{vm.data.list[0].temp.day}} °C
 </TempStyle>
   <br>
     <humidityStyle>
    Humidity:

     {{vm.data.list[0].humidity}} %
    </humidityStyle>
    <br>
    <PressureStyle>
         Pressure:
          {{vm.mmrts}} мм.рт.ст
       </PressureStyle>
    </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

.

Comment: чем этот вопрос отличается от [Не запускаеться angular в chrome/](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/588362/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-angular-%D0%B2-chrome)

Comment: Что делает скрипт перед доктайпом?

Comment: @Grundy, собственно, ничем.

Comment: @Qwertiy , отредактировал. В реальном коде его нет.

Comment: Тогда стоило отредактировать предыдущий вопрос. а не создавать новый такой же

Answer (score 0):

Ангуляр у вас не загружается из-за ограничений CSP ([Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Security/CSP)), подробнее применительно к расширениям можно прочитать [в документации](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy).

По умолчанию для расширений блокируются встроенные скрипты (в том числе всяческие атрибуты вроде onclick), а также загрузка скриптов откуда-то из интернета.

Решений тут два. Во-первых, можно скачать файл `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js` и положить его внутрь расширения.

Во-вторых, можно прописать разрешение на обращение к домену `ajax.googleapis.com` в манифесте:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com"
```

Кроме того, тут есть вторая проблема: библиотека Angular активно использует eval - а потому надо также разрешить его использование в CSP:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' ‘unsafe-eval’ https://ajax.googleapis.com"
```

Answer (score -1):

Решение: angular.js.mini надо скачать и закинуть в папку, а не давать ссылку в интернет в расширении. 
Для html ссылка работает, а расширение-нет.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?